# Difference in deploying J2ee app on Portal Sever and AppServer

Tags: websphere, websphere-portal

I want to deploy a J2EE app on Portal Sever this is not a big app it has just one JSP file, if I deploy it on was profile(server1)  rather then portal server profile then i have to  start WAS i.e server1 and i have to check if this port is accessible by my web server.
IS this approach fine or I should not deploy J2ee app on Portal server or is this bad approach

Comment: I answeared again the question, please come back with what you have tried and provide information.

Answer (score 1):

If your J2EE application is developed using **portlets** (JSR 168 Portlet, IBM Portlet) than it should be deployed on the **Portal Server** .
If your application has nothing to do with portlets than you can deploy it on the **WAS**.

Portal Server is designed for portlets, has an WAS attached and runs on top of it. So in either case, the WAS, which comes embedded with the Portal, is needed. *(The portal can be seen as a big application which runs on WAS)*.

More info:

- [Differences between WAS and WPS](http://www.webportalclub.com/2013/05/what-is-difference-between-wps.html)

Comment: My caveat to this is to check licensing - in some of our WebSphere licenses, we are not allowed to install anything on WAS that isn't in direct support of Portal. Just something to double check.

Comment: My Question is I want to access a simple jsp from my portal , how do i do that

Comment: @Anil Yes, but do you have a portlet? What kind of application have you created?

Answer (score 0):

In this answear I will explain you the steps that a beginner should perform to deploy and see the JSP in the browser:

- create the Portlet class: `public class CallMePortlet extends PortletAdapter {}`
- create the portlet.xml file
- create the WAR archive

Then, on the Portal:

- login in the administration module of the portal. Something like:
  `localhost:100xx/wps/portal/admin`. Here you can create pages and you
  need the create a page. This page will be created in a hierarchy of
  pages under **Home** page
- load the portlet in the Portal, you have in the administration this option. Here you will load from the disk the WAR created in the first part.
- go again to the page you created earlier and this time select the portlet to deploy on this page.

Finally, exit the administration module and go to the Home page then hierarchically to the page you created.

Comment: @Setila Thank you for your explanation I am portal developer and J2ee app, the JSP page i want to access for my portal server is  a proxy page it is used in one of services I can paste same code in portal but SInce it has send reqeust to server and  send reponse back to from server so I dont feel portlet would be better here and having tried it dint work correctly .SO i want to acess JSP page which is deployed ON was so hwo do i do it i dont want to create a profile for was just because of one JSP